# Returning a MVC 5 view with path specified via jQuery AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I use a jQuery AJAX call to an MVC5 ActionResult to return a View. The ActionResult returns the view allied to it (well supposedly) but what is displayed is the layout page, not the view I want.

I've tried a lot of the answers on this site, including relative URLs to the view or some other view even, but without success

```
public ActionResult GetSomePartialView(string personId)
{
  IdentityUserViewModel identityUserViewModel = new IdentityUserViewModel();
  ExBool iUser = personBo.GetById(int.Parse(personId), out Person model);
  return View(model);
  //return View("~/Views/Person/EditPerson.cshtml",model);
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Person/GetSomePartialView/",
  data: jsonModelData,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (jsReturnArgs) {
    $("#tabDetails").html(jsReturnArgs); // the HTML I returned from the controller
  },
  error: function (errorData) {
    alert("error: " + errorData);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the PartialView Method instead of View method.

```
return PartialView(viewName, model);
```

And change the sign method to return a partial view result

```
 public PartialViewResult GetSomePartialView(string personId)
 {
     IdentityUserViewModel identityUserViewModel = new IdentityUserViewModel();
      ExBool iUser = personBo.GetById(int.Parse(personId), out Person model);
      return PartialView("viewName",model);
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result is unchanged. It still renders the Layout page.

Comment: There were model errors in the partial. Fixing those, returning it as a View enabled my original code to work and also the suggested answer (where the partial is moved into the shared folder or pathed correctly)